# Loop to reassign vector elements matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector, while-loop

In Matlab, I have a vector `A` of size 30x1 and another vector `B` of size 3x1.

```
  A = [1.23 2.2 3.3 4.8 5.1 6.7 7.1 8.2 9.9 10.25 11.00 12.1 13.2 14.3 15.4 16.5 17.5 18.1 19.8 20.188 21.2 22.4 23.6 24.1 25.2 26.7 27.8 28.2 29.1 30.3]';

  B = [1.23 10.25 20.188];
```

I want to create a vector `C` of the same size as `A` from `A` and `B` such that

```
  C = [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]';
```

The numbers in `B` are times that are the exact same as elements in `A`, some elements apart, for e.g. `B(2)=A(10)`.

Now I need to write a loop such that every time the loop sees the same number in `B` as in `A` it writes `2` to C until it finds the next element of `B` which is the same as `A` where it will then write `1` until it finds the next same element.

So for e.g.

```
  B(1) = 1.23 and A(1) = 1.23 so C(1:i,1)=2; %where i is the index of the 
next similar element.
```

Can anyone help me as to how to write this loop exactly? I need to make the loop general so not assuming anything about where the positions of the same elements are or could be because I could have different sized vectors (when I need to implement this later in a script).

Thanks!!

Comment: Are the values in both vectors always going to be ascending?

Comment: Is the first value of `A` always going to be the first value of `B`?

Comment: Are the values of `B` always going to be in `A`?

Comment: @excaza yes to all 3 questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start by finding the indices. Try the following:

```
locs = find(ismember(A, B)) % This will give you the required indices
N = numel(locs);

% Pre-allocate the C vector
C = zeros(size(A)); 
L = numel(C);

if ~mod(N, 2)
   C(locs(N):L) = 1;
else
   C(locs(N):L) = 2;
end

% Now start the loop
for i = 1:N-1
    if ~mod(i,2)
       C(locs(i):locs(i+1)-1) = 1;
    else
       C(locs(i):locs(i+1)-1) = 2;
    end
end
```

Hope this helps. You can add error handling to it and find ways to shorten the code.

Comment: Thanks! It works!! After a while I realised that in my data elements of A and B are sometimes not 100% the same for e.g. an element of A could be 19.14 and of B 19.21 but I found a way to find the members within a given "tolerance" and then to use this code! `tol=0.5; ind = any(squeeze(all(abs(bsxfun(@minus, B, permute(A, [3 2 1]))) <= tol, 2)), 1)';
j=1; for i=1:size(A) if ind(i)==1; IND3(j)=i; j=j+1; end; i=i+1; end
IND3=IND3';
locs=IND3;`

Answer (score 1):

How about a vectorized one-liner:

```
mod(cumsum(ismember(A,B)),2)+1
```

No need for loops on this one

Comment: I thought the person needed to write this in a loop otherwise this is how it should be done. +1